# django query latest of multiple dates

Tags: django, django-queryset

I need to find the latest date entry among multiple DateTimeFields.

models.py:

```
class Presentation(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'Start'))
    end = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_(u'End'))
```

I am aware of [latest()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/#latest) which sadly only supports querying a single field.

EDIT: I am looking for a one-query solution, if it exists.

Comment: Of course, one could assume that "end" is always later than "start", but there is no guarantee as users sometimes make mistakes, too.

Comment: I'm not getting your question. Are you trying to find an entry that has the latest date in both `start` and `end`?

Comment: No, I am trying to find the latest overall date. Either start or end, it does not matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a one query solution you can use django's [extra()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) queryset method:

```
latest_obj = Presentaion.objects.extra({"latest_date":"greatest(start, end)"}).order_by('latest_date')[0]
```

This will give you the object with the latest timestamp. `latest_obj` has now an extra attribute `latest_date`

```
latest_obj.latest_date
```

### EDIT:

Using `extra()` is not recommended and will be deprecated in future versions.

> Use this method as a last resort. This is an old API that we aim to deprecate at some point in the future. Use it only if you cannot express your query using other queryset methods.

In django1.9 a database function [`Greatest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) was introduced. Now you can use `annotate` for that:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest
latest_obj = Presentaion.objects.annotate(last_date=Greatest('start', 'end')).order_by('last_date')[0]
```

Comment: I am getting an ProgrammingError: syntax error at or near "end", but really like the idea!

Comment: hm. It is working with one of my models. What is your django and python version and what database?

Comment: Django 1.6 (it's a legacy project...), Python 2.7.6, Postgres 9.3.11

Comment: The SQL Statement itself seems to be fine, tough: SELECT (GREATEST( start, end )) AS "latest_date", ...

Comment: This seems to be a problem on my end - i ran the raw sql statement directly to the database, and it worked as expected. SOLD!

Comment: Your're welcome. Maybe it's related to your django version. You should definitely think about upgrading!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with two queries. One for `start` and one for `end`:

```
latest_start = Presentaion.objects.latest('start')
latest_end = Presentaion.objects.latest('end')

if latest_start.start > latest_end.end:
    latest_date = latest_start.start
else:
    latest_date = latest_end.end
```

Comment: That is one good solution, but not quite the perfect one as it shifts the comparison to python instead the database.

Comment: You're right. I added a new answer with a "one-query" solution.